# Will MySQL full-text-search return the results I need?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a keyword field with a list of 5 keywords for each item. example below:

```
2008, Honda, Accord, Used, Car
```

Will MySQL full text return the item above for the following search requests?

```
2008 Honda Accord
Honda Accord
Used Car
```

If so, how well will this hold up when searching through fifty thousand plus records?

Answer (score 1):

You can use LIKE operator. WHERE x LIKE '%Honda%Accord%'. You get all rows contains *Honda*Accord*. I think is so helpful for your problem. Fifty thousand is small amout of records, you can not thinking about performance problem, you must only have index on this column.

Comment: I do not want to use LIKE.  I have 50k records now, but it is growing quickly and I would like to increase the performance.